# Unable to properly add entries from a file into a 2d array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble adding items to a 2d pointer array in C.  My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include "pg3_methods.h"

void load_input(char path[])
{
char ** input = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char));

// Variable to hold current word
char * currentWord = malloc(sizeof(char));

// Set file equal to the path
FILE * file;
file = fopen(path, "r");
int i = 0;

// Checks if file is null
if (file == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "File %s does not exist.", path);
}

// If not null, cycles through file and adds entries
while (!feof(file))
{
    fscanf(file, "%s", currentWord);
    input = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    input[i] = currentWord;
    printf("input[%i] = %s\n", i, currentWord);
    i++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", input[i]);
}
}
```

The output is this:

```
input[0] = The
input[1] = small
input[2] = fox
input[3] = jumped
input[4] = over
input[5] = the
input[6] = red
input[7] = fence
input[8] = bad
input[9] = The
input[10] = small
input[11] = fox
input[12] = jumped
input[13] = over
input[14] = the
input[15] = red
input[16] = fence
input[17] = bad
input[18] = The
input[19] = small
input[20] = fox
input[21] = jumped
input[22] = over
input[23] = the
input[24] = red
input[25] = fence
input[26] = bad

(null)
(null)
bad
(null)
(null)
bad
(null)
(null)
```

As you can see, it is working within the while loop but, once it exits the loop, it is all messed up.  Any suggestions of how I can make this work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  (NOTE: The words in the first part of the output are from a separate text file.)

Comment: You only ever malloc space for one char. Haven't looked at all your code, but I'm pretty sure that isn't what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char ** input = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

This allocates enough memory for a **single character**, which is probably not what you want. Instead, you should do something like:

```
char ** input = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * WORD_COUNT);
```

which will allocate several pointers to `char`. You can now treat this as an array of `char*`.

```
char * currentWord = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Again, you are only allocating a single character.  You probably need to allocate more memory than this.

Now let's look at the body of your `while` loop:

```
fscanf(file, "%s", currentWord);
input = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
input[i] = currentWord;
```

There are several problems here. First of all, you continually write over the previous word in memory. Second of all, you allocate a new block of memory for `input` and forget about the old memory block which was allocated (this is a memory leak). Finally, every pointer in the `input` array (assuming you fix things to allocate an array instead of a single character) all point to the same string in memory.

To fix these problems, you should follow this pseudocode:

1. Allocate enough memory for `input` to store pointers to every word that you will read in.
2. In the loop:

   1. Allocate memory for one word
   2. Read the word into the allocated memory
   3. Assign one of the pointers in `input` to point at this word just read in

If you have difficulty translating this process into C code, please let us know with a new question.